# Can I raise exception in python pyramid without rollback?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I would like to know if there is an elegant way to raise Exception in my code but do not rollback whole session in my pyramid python web application.

Use case:
After the wrong login credentials, I would like to increment some counter on User table. After n times when counter exceed V value, I would like to raise Exception that account is blocked and further actions are not possible. Unfortunately raising exceptions rollback whole session and counter is not incrementing correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not mess with these, I would rather create a new session, do an update, and committed this new session, and let the exception go through.

To create a new session: It pretty much depends on how you have your project organized. For example, I have:

```
config.registry['dbsession_factory']
```

Which is then accessible in the request as

```
request.registry['dbsession_factory'].
```

You will be able to find out in something like `project/models/__init__.py`. Then you can use it as follows:

```
db = request.registry['dbsession_factory']()
try:
    db.query(...whatever.i.need...)
except:
    db.rollback()
finally:
    db.commit()
```

Comment: I totally agree with this by the way. The primary dbsession should be used for “successful” or “primary” work and if there’s other data you want to record outside of that then it should be done in a separate session/transaction that you would commit regardless of error conditions.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! Actually documentation recommends the same way of handling it.